# How do I make a form field read only or otherwise non editable in a django generic FormView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that pre-populates the user field on page load with the currently logged in user. I would like to grey this field out so that the user can't change it to a user who isn't logged in. I would like for the user to be able to change the rest of the fields. I've tried using the **init** function on the model form and the view to no avail.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

forms.py:

```
class PtoRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # Model to be used in the form.
        model = PtoHistory
        # Define which model fields to include in the form.
        fields = [
            'user',
            'start',
            'end',
            'leave_type',
        ]
        # Attach input widgets to fields for a friendlier user interface.
        widgets = {
            'start': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'start'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3),
            'end': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'end'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3),
    }
```

views.py:

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/index.html'
    form_class = PtoRequestForm
    success_url = '/accounts'
    # Pre-populates the form with the specified values on page load.
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'user': self.request.user}

    # Function runs when form is submitted. Do whatever needed to the form before it's saved to the db.
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)

    # Function runs on page load. Gather any information needed for the template.
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Initialize context
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Grab all ptoHistory records from the database, selecting only the values desired.
        pto_history = PtoHistory.objects.values('start', 'end', 'pk', 'user_id')
        # Convert the django queryset to json so that fullcalendar can work with it on the frontend.
        json_pto_history = json.dumps(list(pto_history), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        # Save the converted json to the context to be returned to the front end.
        context['ptoHistory'] = json_pto_history
        return context
```

Here is a screenshot of my form. The user shouldn't be able to change the user field but the rest of the fields are ok to change.

[image]

Comment: you can override \__init__\ PtoRequestForm and in it add self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my model form I didn't include the 'user' field like so:

forms.py:

```
class PtoRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # Model to be used in the form.
        model = PtoHistory
        # Define which model fields to include in the form.
        fields = [
            'start',
            'end',
            'leave_type',
        ]
        # Attach input widgets to fields for a friendlier user interface.
        widgets = {
            'start': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'start'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3),
            'end': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'end'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3),
        }
```

And then in my form_valid function I just attached the user who was currently logged in before I saved it to the database like so:

views.py:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        new_form = form.save(commit=False)
        new_form.user = self.request.user
        new_form.save()
        return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as follow:

```
class PtoRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # Model to be used in the form.
        model = PtoHistory
        # Define which model fields to include in the form.
        fields = [
            'user',
            'start',
            'end',
            'leave_type',
        ]
        # Attach input widgets to fields for a friendlier user interface.
        widgets = {
            'start': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'start'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3),
            'end': DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'end'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3),}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(PtoRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: Where exactly do I place this in my code? I've tried several things like this and they either don't change anything or throw an error.

Comment: Awesome we're making progress. After doing this the field was grayed out but I could still select the drop down menu and change the user. Is this something to do with 'readonly' maybe? Is there another attribute that would work so that the user couldn't even select the dropdown menu?

Comment: If you have to make it select element. you can add disabled attribute = True. The problem is that if you made this, it will not be sent back after submitting. You can change also the widget to textfield as follow. self.fields['user'].widget=TextInput()

Comment: Yeah that's what I was just reading. Could I disable it and just throw the user on in the backend after it's been submitted?

Comment: If you changed the widget to TextInput, you will not have to disable it and readonly attribute will do the job and it will be sent to the backend. If you decided to go through Selectbox, you have two options. If the user is attached to request, you can get access to this by request.user. If not, you will have to add a hidden field with the username.

Comment: I changed the widget to a TextInput and now when I try to save it says: Cannot assign "'FlashBanistan'": "PtoHistory.user" must be a "User" instance. The user is a foreignkey field to my User model. Any idea on how to overcome this?

Comment: in form_valid function, you can get the user foreign key as form.fields['user'] = User.objects.get(username=form.fields['user'])

Comment: Ahmed, sadly when I click submit it doesn't even make it into my form_valid function before it throws the error so I can't reassign the user field to self.request.user. I would be ok with just leaving that field out on the form that the user sees and adding it in the backend but every implementation of this I have tried fails.